# Login loop after nvidia driver update

Tags: nvidia, gnome, login

I know this question has been asked before but non of them solutions worked for me.

Edit: My graphics card is 730GT

I'm running ubuntu 17.10 (upgraded from 17.04) and after updating and rebooting, I couldn't get in to my account. I faced this problem before and I followed everything I did last time ([Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)). I still couldn't get in. I tried with a new account and I was able to log in to that. I've tried uninstalling and installing 387, 384, 381 none of them worked.

And when I logged in using nouveau I couldn't open gnome-terminal or nautilus. But they both working fine on my new account. I don't know whether they are related to the login loop but everything was working fine before the update. I can run nautilus thought uxterm but with gnome-terminal I get this:

```
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached
```

Is there a way to fix this without reinstalling ubuntu?

Answer (score -1):

Okay, finally able to login.

Instead of installing drivers using apt-get. I tried using the drivers from nvidia site. It worked.

Edit:

Followed steps:

Downloaded 384.98 Linux 64bit driver (http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/126577/en-us)

Uninstalled nvidia drivers I've installed using the ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa.

```
sudo apt purge nvidia-*
```

Reboot.

Logged in to the tty and installed the downloaded driver.

```
chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.98.run 
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.98.run
```

After another reboot, I was able to login without looping back to the login screen.

But  still can't open gnome-terminal, nautilus or gedit from the dock or the dash (They all can be open using UXTerm or from another user account and shows no errors when running them).

Comment: Can you **[edit]** this to expand it with specific details about exactly what driver you downloaded and how you installed it?