# Can't open gnome-terminal, nautilus or gedit

Tags: gnome, nautilus, gedit

I've had some problems after recent nvidia driver update to Ubuntu 17.10 (ubuntu on xorg) ([Login loop after nvidia driver update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972562/login-loop-after-nvidia-driver-update)) But I was able to fix the login loop by reinstalling nvidia drivers downloaded from nvidia driver page.

But problems with gnome-terminal, nautilus and gedit still here. I can't open any of them by clicking on icons (dash, dock). I can open gedit and nautilus from UXTerm but gnome-terminal shows this error:

```
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached
```

But

```
dbus-launch gnome-terminal
```

Works.

All those are running in the new user account I created.

I've tried reinstalling all of them, running

```
localectl set-locale LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

But none of them worked. Any way to fix this thing?

Comment: Can you try to set the locale setting in the GUI settings dialog and tell us the outcome?

Comment: I changed language from US english to UK english and back to US. Now all three apps are opening up.

Comment: O.k. then let me write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your locale setting have not been saved. To fix this you can set them via the GUI dialog in settings which is actually pretty easy.

After that the applications should be back to normal.