# Ubuntu 18.04: Videos not playing, can only login using "Ubuntu on Wayland"

Tags: nvidia, 18.04

Today I was facing the issue that videos (YouTube and other sites) in Chrome and Firefox won't start playing (I can jump around single frames inside the videos by clicking in the timeline) while it was working fine until earlier today.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a DELL M3800 (Nvidia GPU).

I tried uninstalling `nvidia-340` and now I'm no longer able to login to "Ubuntu" but only "Ubuntu on Wayland" at login screen.

Re-installing `nvidia-340` or installing `nvidia-390` didn't fix it.

When choosing "Ubuntu" the screen turns black for a second and then returns back to the login screen me being logged out again.

Update: I tried to set `nomodeset` in GRUB but this didn't fix it.

Update 2: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` didn't fix it neither.

Update 3: uncommenting `#WaylandEnable=false` and re-commenting it in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` seems to have fixed the login loop. But now I'm now longer able start terminal. Mouse turns into a spinner for a few seconds but terminal is not starting.

Update 4: `dbus-launch gnome-terminal` launches terminal after I ran `sudo chown username.username -R .dbus`

Update 5: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972882/cant-open-gnome-terminal-nautilus-or-gedit) fixed my broken terminal (and by reading the answer I noticed Nautilus was broken as well).

Update 6: Fix from Update 5 is not permanent.

Update 7: switching back to `bash` from `zsh` fixed the terminal/nautilus issues permanently. But I'm still not able to play videos and I'm not able to install any of the Nvidia drivers.

Update 8: Update 7 was not permanent.

Answer (score 0):

I partially solved the issue doing this:

1. `dpkg-divert --list | grep nvidia-340` to show all nvidia-340 dependecies
2. For all of them I did `dpkg-divert --remove *path*`
3. `apt --fix-broken install`
4. `apt update`
5. `apt upgrade`
6. `ubuntu-drivers devices`
7. `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
   Then `reboot`.
   In case the screen resolution is lower than possible follow [this tutorial](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-desktop/)

Hope you'll solve.