# Can't open gnome-terminal, natulius, gedit, clocks

Tags: 20.04, gnome

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and can't open gnome-terminal, nautilus, clocks and gedit.
All theese apps are gnome apps so I may not even be able to open some other gnome apps.
Now I use xterm and trying to open terminal and natulius but with no luck. Comment to get more information.

[image: No response of natulius]

Comment: What happened before your system started to behave like this?

Comment: Marking this question as duplicate because it solved my problem, https://askubuntu.com/questions/972882/cant-open-gnome-terminal-nautilus-or-gedit/972893#972893